CMake - conditional statements on Boost version
The C++ Boost 1.74 that ships with Ubuntu 22.04 has code that is incompatible with C++20. There is an alternate file available that I need to copy prior to stating the build.
The following is a snippet from the CMakeLists.txt file.
If I comment out the "if($Boost_VERSION..." and leave the file it works fine, but is not future proof.
My question is how to do the comparison for the boost version.
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
set(Boost_DEBUG TRUE)
set(Boost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE OFF)
find_package(Boost 1.74.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS program_options locale)

include(wtOptions.txt)
# Patch the boost include library for a C++2z error.
#if(${Boost_VERSION_MINOR} > 75)
  file(COPY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/files/storage.hpp DESTINATION /usr/include/boost/numeric/ublas)
#endif()

`
The error I get is
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:35 (if):
  if given arguments:

    "74" ">" "75"

  Unknown arguments specified

The idea is to patch automatically if the boost version is 1.74. I do not want to have to use a more recent version of boost and need to stick with the base installed version.

In CMake operator > is expressed with keyword GREATER: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/if.html#comparisons. Note also that you could omit dereference of the operand: if(Boost_VERSION_MINOR GREATER 75).

I believe that you need to do the conditional like this:
if(${Boost_VERSION_MINOR} GREATER 75)
  # ...
endif()

Use GREATER rather than > for numerical comparisons.
